# SpringSecurity : always redirect logged in users to a page

Tags: spring

Spring security has a nice feature, it remembers the url of request resource and redirect users to that resource after authentication is successful. But I want users always redirected to some other page, just after user logs in. How is it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your spring-security configuration use following:

```
<http>
        <form-login default-target-url='/some/other/page' always-use-default-target="true"/>
</http>
```