# How to get redirected to a method at login/logout before target-url called in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to record current time of Login (in a method or object) once the login is successful and assign LastLogin time to current login time at logout. I am using spring security for login, logout. But I don't know how to take control to a method before it goes to the target-url.

spring-security.xml

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/home/currentTime" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" default-target-url="/home"/>

<security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/home/copyLastloginToCurrentLoginTime" logout-url="/logout" />
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/currentTime", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void recordCurrentLoginTime(Model model) { 
    // code to record current time 
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/copyLastloginToCurrentLoginTime", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void changeLastLoginTime(Model model) {
    //code to copy current to last time 
}
```

**Problem**

I get Error 404 for - project-title/j_spring_security_check URL and when I try to debug, it doesn't come into the controller methods at all.

Should I use some filters or something else for this purpose?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229459/springsecurity-always-redirect-logged-in-users-to-a-page) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067736/how-to-process-a-form-login-using-spring-security-spring-mvc) and but that didn't help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Write your own **[`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)** and **[`LogoutSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html)**.

Example:

**spring-security.xml** :

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
    login-processing-url="/login_check"
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
    authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
/>

<security:logout
    logout-url="/logout"
    success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler"
/>
```

**AuthenticationSuccessHandler**

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // changeLastLoginTime(username)
        userService.changeLastLoginTime(authentication.getName());

        setDefaultTargetUrl("/home");
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

**LogoutSuccessHandler**

```
@Component
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (authentication != null) {
            // do something 
        }

        setDefaultTargetUrl("/login");
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);       
    }
}
```

Comment: One caveat I would mention is that this sets the default for all users every time, so once it is set it becomes the global redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can map a default-target-url in your mapping like

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
    login-processing-url="/login_check"
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
    default-target-url = "/welcome"
    authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

When the user is authenticated it is the time when user accessed your system. Make a update through DAO in the user table with current date and time.
Simple process and you are done