# Spring - Do some action after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to store actual date in DB after a successful user login. How to do that ? Filter, handler or something ? Need help.

Comment: You mean "login" (not "logging"), don't you?

Comment: @meriton I'm not English-speaking, but I think so. I've changed title.

Comment: **See answer** : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769654/how-to-get-redirected-to-a-method-at-login-logout-before-target-url-called-in-spr/6770785#6770785

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
           @Override
       public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) 
       throws IOException, ServletException {
       //your code here    
     }
}
```

config:

```
<beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler"
            class="your.pachage.decleration.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>
```

Comment: Thanks:) I've just corrected Your example (implements -> extends)

Comment: In spring 3, remember to configure the `authentication-success-handler-ref` in `<security:form-login>`