# spring security logout trigger

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to remove logged out user from a Hashmap I have for logged in users but I don't find the way to do this as when I press the logout link. It just redirected to login page.

In spring security I have

```
 <logout invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-success-url="/" 
        logout-url="/logout.htm"/>
```

logout link is like

```
 <a href="logout.htm">Logout</a>
```

When I press this link it just go to my login mapping

```
 @RequestMapping("login")
public ModelAndView login(){}
```

and when I try to get user detail using

```
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

it returns me anonymous user. So how can I get the logged out user detail.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint about the `LogoutSuccessHandler` is correct. However, you have to consider that configuring `success-handler-ref` and `logout-success-url` are mutually exclusive if I'm not mistaken. Hence, you need to implement the forwarding to URL  manually in your success handler. Pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770785/131929

Comment: Good point. My answer was updated according to your hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Add an implementation of **org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler** interface as a bean to your security context.

Then you can use it:

```
<logout success-handler-ref="yourLogoutSuccessHandler" />
```

**EDIT.**
As mentioned by Marcel this solution will not work out of the box because you can't mix *success-handler-ref* and *logout-success-url* attributes ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770785/131929)). I prefer slightly different solution : instead of inheritance, you can use composition:

1. Prepare configuratio for **SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler** bean.
2. Set up *logout-success-url* via corresponding *defaultTargetUrl* property.
3. Inject **SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler** bean into your **CustomUrlLogoutSuccessHandler** using **LogoutSuccessHandler** interface and call it after doing your stuff.

Advantage is that you will be less coupled with a framework code. So you will have less problems in a case of migration from Spring Security 3.1 to Spring Security Y.Y

Answer (score 0):

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
authentication.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your applicationContext-security.xml file add the success-handler like below

```
< logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" success-handler-ref="com.mycompany.security.SpringSecurityLogoutHandler" />
```

Create the Class which will be implemneting `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler` interface and in it's logout method do all the stuff you want at the time of logout.