# How to log SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess with Spring Aspect?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I try to log when user is successfully logged with Spring Security. I use Logging Aspect :

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

@Before("execution(* com.jle.athleges.web.controller.MemberController.*(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    log.info("INFO - logBefore() is running!");
    log.info(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(..))", returning = "result")
public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) throws Throwable {
    log.info(">>> user: " + ((Authentication) result).getName());
}

@Around("execution(* org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(..))")
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(){
    log.info(">>> user " + (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()) + " is now connected");
}
}
```

Method after is running fine but log twice. I try with onAuthenticationSuccess but nothing is writed in console.

I use sample explained in [Capture successful login with AspectJ and Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186087/capture-successful-login-with-aspectj-and-spring-security) but it is not working.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !

I created a new SuccessHandler bean :

```
public class SecurityAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

}

And second point is to add it as a bean in the config and set it in formLogin :

```
    @Bean
public SecurityAuthenticationSuccessHandler getSuccessHandler(){
    return new SecurityAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
}

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll().and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
```