# Custom locale redirect after login - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, spring-security

I am writing a simple prototype Spring MVC 3.2 with Spring Security. My requirements specify that the urls must be of the following structure

```
http://app-name/{locale}/signin
http://app-name/{locale}/logout
http://app-name/{locale}/account
```

I have implemented a Filter to set the locale as a request attribute and successfully managed to get everything working, except spring-security login process, where it does redirect to /account on successful login.

I was wondering whether it is possible to define some kind of wrappers for these actions?

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/signin"
                         login-processing-url="/security_check"
                         username-parameter="username"
                         password-parameter="password"
                         authentication-failure-url="/signin"
                         default-target-url="/account"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by writing my own [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) and [LogoutSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html). See the answer below for more details

[how to get redirected to a method at login/logout before target-url called in spring-security, spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769654/how-to-get-redirected-to-a-method-at-login-logout-before-target-url-called-in-sp)